# py2exe executable doesn't start

Tags: python, py2exe

**Update 3:** I've used pyinstaller + shipped my code in one script and it works perfectly!

**Update 2:** I've put all my scripts in a single .py file but there are like 2000 lines and it's really not the way I would like to do it. Anyway it seems to lead me to a new error/solving trail but I do want to know the answer to how to generate a .exe with py2exe if it's outsourced in different scripts so if you have any idea...

**Update 1:** I've tried with a simple GUI: it works, but I've tried launching the simple GUI from another module and it doesn't work so I think there's definitely something here. I don't know if I'm clear but I have a "simple GUI" which works but I tried a "start module" which basically just import the "simple GUI" and runs it but this doesn't work.

Since yesterday I've finished a piece of code I've been working of for two weeks. It works fine when I launch it from python and does exactly what I want.

But - there is always a but - the thing is that I don't want my end user to have to install python or even use Portable Python (which I'm using by the way, version 2.7.2.1 on windows xp 32 bits if it helps).

I would like the program to be at best a stand-alone exe or at least a folder with a lot of files and an executable.

So I've made some research before going here and I discovered py2exe. I've been struggling with it for a while but now I've finally succeeded to generate a folder with a lot of files and an executable.

So what's the problem would you say? Well, when I run the executable nothing happens. It's not entirely true, a prompt window appears for 1 second then close and then nothing happens whereas a GUI should show.

I don't know if the problem comes from here but my program is separated into different modules like gui.py, calc.py, blablabla.py, etc.

I've tried to google my problem but didn't find anything worth of interest so far.

Here is my setup.py :

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
setup(console=['guiapp.py'])
```

The module that I launch on python and which starts everything guiapp.py :

```
import MainWindowApp
import CumulativeLogger
import logging
import gettext
_ = gettext.gettext

logging.basicConfig()
l = logging.getLogger()
l.setLevel(logging.INFO)
cl = CumulativeLogger.CumulativeLogger()
l.info(_('Lancement du Programme'))
MainWindowApp.MainWindowApp(cl).run()
```

And finally the MainWindowApp.py (shortened) which should launch the GUI:

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox
import tkFileDialog
import logging
import ViewLog
import ThreadsConnector
import ActionWindow
import gettext
import app2
_ = gettext.gettext
import os

class MainWindowApp:
    def __init__(self, log):
        self.log    = log
        self.logger = logging.getLogger(self.__class__.__name__)

    def run(self):
        self.root = root = Tk()
        root.title(_('QuickGen'));

        #Buttons and things like that

        root.mainloop()

    def alotoffunctiontomakeitrun
```

By the way I should mention that I have tried to replace my whole code by a little GUI that does nothing except be there and it worked so I really don't know what to think...

Comment: Is there an error showing up on that console when it flashes by? Run the exe from the console and see if it spits out any useful information, also use print statements to help you debug.

Comment: What is your actual problem?  You should get some sort of stack trace when you attempt to run your executable that will indicate which modules did not get bundled.  py2exe works perfectly well with multiple source files / modules - otherwise no one would use it.

Comment: Nothing shows on the console I think the problem comes from the fact that some scripts have to be consolemode and others windowmode but I don't know how to tell it to py2exe.